# Add dynamic width based on parent div

Tags: jquery, width, parent, each

what i am trying to do is to extract the width of let's say: .ow_newsfeed_left (it has different widths) and then add that width to a child div. 
i'm trying using `each` but it will asign only the first value.

This is the code i got so far

```
$('.ow_newsfeed_left').each(function() {
    $(".ow_newsfeed_string").css("left", $( '.ow_newsfeed_left' ).width() + "px");
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Where is `.ow_newsfeed_string` relevant to `.ow_newsfeed_left` - could you post the HTML struct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time through, you're asking to set the `left` style of *all* `.ow_newsfeed_string` elements to the `width()` of *all* `.ow_newsfeed_left` elements (which, yes, will be the first `width` property found).

You need to trim the scope down:

```
$('.ow_newsfeed_left').each(function() {
   $(".ow_newsfeed_string", this).css("left", $( this ).width() + "px");
});
```

Now we're setting the width on `.ow_newsfeed_string` elements *within* the element we're looking at right now (`this`), to the width of that specific element.

Comment: this makes everything a lot more clear. Thank you for teaching me this!